# Upload Ajax - Php

Tags: php, ajax

Estou tentando efetuar o upload de um arquivo PDF via Ajax e Php.
Porém não consigo.

HTML

```
<script>

   var client = new XMLHttpRequest();

   function upload(){

      var file = document.getElementById("uploadfile");

      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("upload", file.files[0]);
      formData.append("MAX_FILE_SIZE", '30000');
      formData.append("userfile", 'pdf');

      client.open("post", "upload.php", true);
      client.send(formData);

   }

   client.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if (client.readyState == 4 && client.status == 200){
         $("#resposta").html(client.responseText);
      }
   }

</script>

<input type="file" id="uploadfile" name="uploadfile" />
<input type="button" value="upload" onclick="upload()" />
```

PHP

```
<?php

$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo '<pre>';

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Arquivo válido e enviado com sucesso.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possível ataque de upload de arquivo!\n";
}

echo "<br><br><br>";

echo 'Aqui está mais informações de debug:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";

?>
```

O PHP não retorna nenhum erro, porém não é feito o upload do arquivo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Além da situação citada pelo [@Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66465/3635), existem outros problemas:

1. Para cada execução ajax é necessário um novo `new XMLHttpRequest()`, ou seja, você está usando apenas um `new XMLHttpRequest()` para todas requisições que irá fazer, isto não irá funcionar.
2. Para cada novo `xmlhttprequest`, você deverá definir um novo `.onreadystatechange = function(){};`

Código corrigido:

```
function upload(){
  var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
  client.open("post", "upload.php", true);
  client.onreadystatechange = function(){
     if (client.readyState == 4 && client.status == 200){
        $("#resposta").html(client.responseText);
     }
  };

  var file = document.getElementById("uploadfile");

  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("upload", file.files[0]);
  formData.append("MAX_FILE_SIZE", '30000');
  formData.append("userfile", 'pdf');

  client.send(formData);
}
```

Comment: Ótimo, muito obrigado ! Melhorou bastante

Answer (score 1):

Muda `$_FILES['userfile']` para `uploadfile` conforme tens no `name` do HTML. O `$_FILES` vai buscar o `name` do input `name="uploadfile" />` e coloca-o no array.

Podes também consultar o que o files têm via `var_dump($_FILES);` para debug.

Comment: Certo. Obrigado !

Answer (score 1):

Tente adicionar no seu XMLHttpRequest:

```
client.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Eu porém conheço outro método para realizar o upload, tendo ela somente a limitação de permitir enviar um arquivo por vez apenas:

```
function upload(){
    var inputFile = document.getElementById("uploadfile");
    var file = inputFile.files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();

    client.open("post", "upload.php", true);
    client.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");       
    client.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
    client.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.size);

    client.send(file);
}
```

E no PHP:

```
<?php

$filename = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME'];
$filesize = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE'];

$in = fopen('php://input','r');
$out = fopen('uploads/'.$filename, 'x');
while($data = fread($in, 1024)) 
    fwrite($out, $data);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No seu form você adicionou isso aqui?

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Isso faz com que o upload funcione corretamente.

Comment: Sim, mesmo assim não está dando certo !