# Upload de imagem a partir do celular com javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou criando um app de vistoria com javascript ou jquery.

O app salva tudo dentro do próprio celular, para depois ser enviando para o servidor, pois nem sempre tem sinal de internet bom.

### Exemplo dos dados salvos:

[image: Dados salvos no SQLite]

### Questão:

Como fazer o upload do arquivo do arquivo, já que tenho apenas o link de onde foi salvo?

Agradeço a todos que poderem me ajudar.

### Código:

```
function upsync() {
  db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT ID, id_ar, id_ambiente, foto, obs FROM vistorias_fotos WHERE id_ar=?', [id_ar], function (tx, resultado) {

      let rows = resultado.rows;

      for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {


        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "https://testes.musite.net/app/up_vistorias.php",
          data: {acesso: 'ok',
                 id_ar: rows[i].id_ar,
                 id_ambiente: rows[i].id_ambiente,
                 foto: rows[i].foto, //->   file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/br.com.nomedoapp.app/cache/1578505903880.jpg
                 obs: rows[i].obs,
                },
          success: function(data) {
            if (data == 'ok'){
              alert('Dados enviado ao MySQL');
            }
          }
        });



      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta usar `new FormData();` (leia: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append), que é uma API nativa do JavaScript, e aplicar assim:

```
var form = new FormData();

form.append('acesso', 'ok');
form.append('id_ar', rows[i].id_ar);
form.append('id_ambiente', rows[i].id_ambiente);
form.append('acesso', 'ok');
form.append('obs', rows[i].obs);
form.append('foto', rows[i].foto);

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "https://testes.musite.net/app/up_vistorias.php",
  data: form,

  /*é necessário estas duas propriedades estarem como FALSE*/
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,

  success: function(data) {
    if (data == 'ok'){
      alert('Dados enviado ao MySQL');
    }
  }
});
```

Se necessitar enviar um nome customizado da foto, faça:

```
form.append('foto', rows[i].foto, 'teste.jpg');
```

O seu caso sendo um webView que está rodando creio que funcione, mas não posso testar no momento, então se isto não funcionar, pode tentar fazer o uso de `Blob` e `FileReader` (esta parte da resposta após testado irei remover)

---

Se procura o upload for em JavaScript, pode usar assim: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66470/3635 e se for upload de um arquivo "salvo" como o da pergunta aqui, deve ficar assim:

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();

client.open("POST", "https://testes.musite.net/app/up_vistorias.php", true);

client.onreadystatechange = function(){
 if (client.readyState == 4){
    if (client.status >= 200 && client.status < 300) {
        //Sucesso HTTP
        if (client.responseText == 'ok'){
          alert('Dados enviado ao MySQL');
        }
    } else {
        //Erro
    }
 }
};

var form = new FormData();

form.append('acesso', 'ok');
form.append('id_ar', rows[i].id_ar);
form.append('id_ambiente', rows[i].id_ambiente);
form.append('acesso', 'ok');
form.append('obs', rows[i].obs);
form.append('foto', rows[i].foto);

client.send(form);
```